# The port 8180 specified in my application-dev.yml is closed on my debian serveur

Tags: jhipster

I have a copy of my **jhipster** app on my debian server and I changed the port in the **application-dev.yml** to **8180**.
I lunch it in dev mode and I try a remote access and the serveur refuse the connection: ***ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED***
So I type this command: **nmap -p81 my_ip** and it results that my port is closed.

Now I search how to open the port and make my app remote access.
Thanks you in advance !

Comment: Can you access it locally using `curl http://localhost:8081` ?

Comment: I did not test it locally, but let me have a look and make you a feedback. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to configure iptables ?
https://upcloud.com/community/tutorials/configure-iptables-debian/

Comment: Here is the result of local access 

# curl http://localhost:8180
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8180: Connection refused

Comment: No, I'll try to configure it now

Comment: Do you see any error in your app logs when you start it? How do you start it ? Also in logs, the app prints the URL where it can be reached including port if sucessfully started.

Comment: no, I get no error. I start it typing ./mvnw and the URL printed is http://my_ip:configured_port

Comment: When I use command line to set the port, my server refuse to restart and I asked where I bought the server and they told me to set the port from my customer dashboard.
Thanks you very much.